# Get text for a Particular value inside body tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I m trying an Api in Enterprise messaging solution(msg91) : Get Balance api Where balance is displayed :

Response :

> [{"balance":1000,"route":"4","type":"SMS"}]

I want to get text from Balance . How can i fetch it using web-driver .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a Balance Class:

   ```
   @Getter
   @Setter
   public class Balance {
     private String balance;
     private String route;
     private String type;
   }
   ```
2. Create a BalancePage class to navigate the page using webDriver, read the response and parse it to json:

   ```
   public class BalancePage extends Page {
     private List<Balance> balances;

     @FindBy(xpath = "html/body")
     WebElement response;

     BalanceConfig config = create(BalanceConfig.class);

     protected BalancePage(TestWebDriver driver) {
       super(driver);
       testWebDriver.setBaseURL(config.url() + "?authkey=" + config.authKey());
       PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(testWebDriver, 30), this);
   }

     private String getBalanceString() {
       return response.getText();
     }

     public void getCurrentBalance() throws IOException {
       ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
       balances = objectMapper.readValue(getBalanceString(), objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Balance.class));
     }
   } 

   public abstract class Page {

     public WebDriver testWebDriver;

     protected Page(WebDriver driver) {
       this.testWebDriver = driver;
      }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

simple string

```
string[] res = response.Split(",")

string balance = new String(res[0].ToCharArray().Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
```